# How can Hyper-V failover be done without Active Directory

Tags: windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

We are a small outfit, and I am running 4 webservers, 2 SQL servers, and a Reporting Server as VM's in Hyper-V on WinServer2016 (datacentre edition). I want to be able to have a failover from this machine (Dell R620) to a copy of it. The servers are not on AD - I'm a dev wearing a Admin hat badly.

Is there something out there that can do this?

Already have replication running from [live] machine to [backup/failover] machine.
However, if stuff goes down, all info that was committed to sql databases since last replication would be lost, and this is the main problem.

I have no AD training at all, and the current setup is a mongrel that started as a BusinessServer2003, migrated to 2008 then to hybrid cloud based by previous employee that has left. I employed a tech thereafter for a period but fired him after he proved incompetent and in process of stealing source code. Sigh.

Not sure if this is do-able, but I want to attack the biggest headaches first.

Answer (score 6):

You can build Failover Cluster without AD. It is supported to work with SQL Server role. For VMs Live Migration won't work. Should help:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/workgroup-and-multi-domain-clusters-in-windows-server-2016/ba-p/372059

You will need shared storage for the cluster. I am not sure if S2D works in such scenario. You can use alternatives such as StarWind VSAN.
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/starwind-virtual-san-for-hyper-v-2-node-hyperconverged-scenario-with-windows-server-2016/